# Using Kicad & proper part symbols: How do I add these types of parts for through-hole PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad, symbol

**Background**

I am attempting to create a hobbyist PCB (Printed Circuit Board).
I'm using some components which I will provide so end-user can assemble them on a PCB (through-hole soldering them on).

My components are a lot of things like the following real-time clock (RTC) component which are easy to use on a breadboard.

[image: real-time clock component]

**Some Part Symbols Not Available**

However, I don't have a way to get symbol files for these types of parts.

I know that the pitch of a stand breadboard holes is something like 2.54mm (so pins are 2.54mm apart).

I'm wondering what the best way to add 6 holes (number of pins in RTC) to my kicad drawing so they are the correct distance?

And, is that basically the proper way to do this?

Here's the very beginning of my PCB in kicad so far with components I was able to download:

1. 40-pin MCU (ATMega4809)
2. momentary push button

[image: kicad basic symbols]

Comment: This footprint *does* exist in KiCad - it's likely to be a 2.54 mm pitch 1x06 pin header. If I were working with some less generic connector (or any part) lacking a footprint, I'd use the datasheet to create a dimensionally accurate footprint in the footprint editor.

Comment: Oh, wow. I will search for that right now.  There are so many parts in there it's a bit overwhelming.  Thanks for the hint.  

Comment: So many to choose from.  Would this be it : https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6YEy.png
Will that just insure there are holes in the PCB?  What are those pin-looking things on the right?  Is that just for reference?  Thanks  Also, write this up as an answer and I'll upvote / set as answer.

Comment: How are you actually intending to mount this part on your PCB? Standing upright? Or with a female header? The part you have selected includes silkscreen on the right for reference; it will fit your RTC module standing up but will have weird silkscreen drawings showing the pins going to the right. I'd expect PinHeader_1x06_P2.54mm_Vertical instead.

Comment: The footprint you linked is for a right-angle header - the yellow square and rings are the pads and holes that will be placed on the board.  The things to the right would be shown on the silkscreen, to show where the component pins extend.  You should be able to find a similar footprint for a vertical header which won't have those pins to the right.

Comment: If you do any amount of PC layout, you will have to make some of your own footprints, either from scratch, or by editing an existing footprint.  You could edit the footprint you found to replace the pin drawing with something representing the RTC module you are using.

Comment: Thanks to all for your comments. You've helped me very much.  I understand now that the part on the right is just the silkscreen that will show up.  @nanofarad thanks for mentioning the exact part I should use. Thanks for all the explanation, I think I can at least get it going enough to do my first PCB design creation and get sample boards.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you are expected to design the footprint for your components, each of them. KiCad might include some defaults, but it is very well possible that the component you need just is not there.

Before diving into symbol drawing, you can go on the manufacturer's website. More often than not, they provide symbol files for most EDA software, and probably even a step file (a 3d model) of the component itself.

For your particular component, samtec makes this kind of pin header and for sure the symbol file is available on their website.